# How can bone names be copied across an axis?

Tags: rigging, bones

If an armature has been created with *X-Axis Mirror* enabled and we are renaming our bones to something more intuitive, and one half is done (example: arm_upper_L, arm_lower_L), how can we copy the names over to the other half of the armature?

I tried doing <kbd>W</kbd> **Flip Names**, but it did not take the names from the other side. I tried this with both the source side selected and then with the destination side selected, but I didn't get the desired result (which would be arm_upper_R, arm_lower_R).

I have been copy/pasting and typing in the difference, but if there's a better way I would like to know about it. **What is the correct way to mirror the bone names over to the other side of an armature?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make Sure you are in Edit Mode!

Step One: Create just ONE side of the armature and name the bones.

Step Two: Select Bones Wanted to copy to across an axis.

Step Three: Set 3D Cursor to origin by hitting Shift-S: 'Cursor to Selected' (Make sure origin is in center of armature).
Step Four: Press Shift+D and click the mouse button

Step Five: Hit Cntrl+M and then hit X (Or y if you are using the y-axis)

Step Six: Click the mouse button and hit w and select 'Flip Names'

Profit!

Comment: Thanks! I had never used the Mirror operation until now - always just scaled -1 on the axis... good to know about that, and it works on meshes too, I see. So Flip Names looks for a bone named something_L.001 and converts it to something_R for example... got it.

Answer (score 0):

A small update to this for blender 2.8. When duplicating with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, check the bottom left for options and you should see a toggle for "Flip Names" and this will actually flip all the bones for you on the axis and link them as if you used <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to mirror extrude them.[image: Duplicating options for bones]

Also when parenting meshes to the rig, you probably want to check the "x-mirror" toggle
[image: parent with automatic weights options]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange, and thank you for contributing an answer. Can you please explain *what has changed* about Flip Names in 2.8 ?